# Java can not figure out the method to be invoked

Tags: java

I haven't found the reason ([in JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)) why java compiler can't chouse appropriate method to execute in following program:

```
public class UpperLevelClass {
    private static String getStringanotherNameMethod(String a, String b) {
        return null;
    }

    private static String firstSignatureMethod(String a, String b) {
        return null;
    }

    static class StaticNestedClass extends UpperLevelClass{
        public void getStringfirstNameMethod(String a, Integer b) {
            getStringanotherNameMethod("test", "fff");//compiles
            firstNameMethod("test", "fff");//error below
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling finishes with following error:

```
error: method firstNameMethod in class StaticNestedClass cannot be applied to given types;
            firstNameMethod("test", "fff");
            ^
  required: String,Integer
  found: String,String
  reason: argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Integer
```

---

Adding some history:

At first I had several `static` method with `default` access in upper level calls and everething compiles and runs(from static nested class) fine. Then `static` methods access was changed to `private` and programm stops compiling due to error in one method (in this case firstNameMethod), but other methods compiles fine.

---

I have tried(thx to @[Jorn Vernee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699139/jorn-vernee)) to compile and run programm in Eclipse and it compiles and runs.

Comment: Does `UpperLevelClass.getString(...);` works?

Comment: Eclipse compiles this fine, but javac fails. Hm...

Comment: Just tossing an idea into the bin for consideration. 

Does this have to do with the fact that the the method declared in the parent class have a `static` modifier, while the child's declaration does not?

Comment: @Jorn Vernee, intresting - is true Eclips(EJC) compiles and runs fine when javac fails with error.

Comment: If you have an answer to your question you can add it below and accept it. Changing your question to incorporate an answer isn't acceptable.

Comment: @Makoto, if you read the question carefully it sounds like "why java compiler can't choose appropriate method" not how I can solve it!!! So I think my changes is clarification of question not an answer.

Comment: The problem is that now it really does appear like you're modifying your question ever so slightly.  I don't see any reason to add any clarification to the question as you have two answers now and it's unclear what your edit is actually doing.

Comment: According to comment of @Jorn Vernee it seems that different compiles behaves differently though it deserves more careful consideration!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for the appropriate method is a two-step process.

Step 1 involves selecting the class to be searched.  The relevant line of the JLS of this step:

> If the *Identifier* appears in the scope of a visible method declaration with that name:
>
> > If there is an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member, let T be the innermost such type declaration. The class or interface to search is T.

Note that it says *Identifier* and not *Signature* here.  This means that it is only looking at the method name at this stage, and not the arguments.  Because `StaticNestedClass` contains a method called `getString`, that is the class to be searched.

It is only when we get to Step 2 that arguments are taken into account.  Because there is no `getString` method in `StaticNestedClass` that are compatible with the method call, this leads compilation to fail.

Answer (score 3):

Because your outer class' static method is `private`, your inner class can't see the declaration.  Removing the `private` keyword is enough to ensure that the method can actually be seen.

Alternatively, the fully qualified name could also be used - that is, invoke the method with `UpperLevelClass.getString("test", "fff");`.

Comment: Renaming the inner class's method to `getString2` causes it to work.

Comment: @JoeC:  Ew.  I wouldn't want to do that since it makes little sense to do it.  The most obvious thing is addressing the scope issue.

Comment: That's not actually true: `private` visibility has lexical scope, so methods of a nested class can see `private` members of the enclosing class.

Comment: @Makoto, thank you for your response it compiles and runs if specify UpperLevelClass or supper or change one of methods signature, but question was about why campilation fails - due to some bug in javac or it's normal behavior.